# Bash: add object to a json file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know how to echo / add text to the end of a file:

```
echo "{ "fruit":"apple" , "amount":"10" }" >> file.txt
```

My question is how to add a object to the json file below:

the file - file.txt (empty):

```
{
"fruit": [

]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
"fruit": [
{ "fruit":"apple" , "amount":"10" } #object to add

]
}
```

Comment: Don't use `bash` for that, but use a real JSON library.

Comment: totally agree, but the my question is; how to add text to the 'middle' of a file with bash. In this case a json file.

Comment: What's the specification of where the object should be added? It can be done with sed, awk, perl, etc. but you need to define the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ed` is the standard text editor.

```
#!/bin/bash

{
ed -s file.json <<EOF
/\"fruit\": \[
a
{ "fruit":"apple" , "amount":"10" } #object to add
.
wq
EOF
} &> /dev/null
```

Don't know why you want to use bash for that, though, there are much better tools around!

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

> $ sed -e '/"fruit":/a{ "fruit":"apple" , "amount":"10" }' file.txt

This will add a line after "fruit". If you want to replace the file with the modified text:

> $ sed -i.bak -e '/"fruit":/a{ "fruit":"apple" , "amount":"10" }' file.txt

will add the line and replace the file with the modified content. The old file will be saved as backup `file.txt.bak`.